# Win10; Can I delete vol0?

Tags: windows-10

I received a warning on my Win10 pro edition about low disk space.

I went to settings and the first thing it calls out is this, vol0.  I've never seen this directory.

Nothing in there is anything I recognize.

Is this directory safe to delete????

[image: A screenshot showing a Windows dialog box with a folder path of C, vol0 and a size of 7.49 gigabytes]

[image: A screenshot showing the contents of vol0 consisting of two folders. The first folder is titled dot gallery and the second is titled Cache Clip, presented as one word.]

[image: A screenshot showing additional folders with long names. Each name consists of a series of random alphanumeric strings separated by hyphens.]

Comment: It looks like something unique to your computer. This is not a Windows File.  It looks some some kind of download and / or video. Move it to a large USB drive and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I received a warning on my Win10 pro edition about low disk space.
>
> I went to settings and the first thing it calls out is this, vol0.
> I've never seen this directory.
>
> Nothing in there is anything I recognize.
>
> Is this directory safe to delete????

This appears to be tourism advertising and / or videos. It is also possibly related to IoT  (VOIO. THE IoT SIMs & IoT CONNECTIVITY NETWORK)

This is not a Windows 10 (or any Windows) folder.

You might look in Program and Features to see if it is something installed and needs to be uninstalled.

Then move it to a large USB drive which will delete it from your computer and keep it backed up.

Answer (score 1):

it is a DaVinci Resolve cache folder. watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onfWsmOcT_Q&ab_channel=HighPerformanceTV

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the short answer by "user1775212", it's the default cache folder of Blackmagic's "DaVinci Resolve".

If you are not using Davinci Resolve anymore, you can uninstall it, and delete the folder.

If using Resolve, configure it and it's projects to store the ".gallery" and "CacheClip" folders on another disk. Look in the Resolve manual for details.